# Workflow Management Service "eats up" memory

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm bothered with what's happening in our servers. I noticed that the Workflow Management Service is taking up most of the memory. I know that the fastest way to do this is to "kill" the task. However, there are other workflows that are hosted in hear. Therefore, killing only one will kill everyone.

Any workaround for this?

Comment: Are you actually running out of memory, or are you just being paranoid?  You know the GC doesn't release memory back to the system unless it absolutely has to, as allocating new memory is costly.  Maybe you should put down task manager and walk away from it.

Comment: Seriously running out of memory....

Comment: Then catch the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx and post the `.ToString()` result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into similar problems and here are my detail findings.
http://serena-yeoh.blogspot.com/2013/08/solving-workflow-management-service.html

You will need to make sure that there are no deleted services or services that can no longer be activated in the Instances table.